# A simple What am I

Tags: riddle

I can be wrapped in flour and baked

I can be made into oils,

You can crack me open and drink from it,

Or directly eat me.

What am I?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can be wrapped in flour and baked

> coconut flour (OP's answer: coconut pie)

I can be made into oils,

> coconut oil

You can crack me open and drink from it,

> coconut water

Or directly eat me.

> shredded coconut

What am I?

> coconut

Comment: Wow so fast. Correct aanswer, but I can't accept for 11 minutes :(

Comment: Thanks. I liked your riddle. I am new here. Hopefully I am able to develop some riddles of my own to contribute.

Comment: Thanks for the formatting help. I was just about to Google how to do that

Comment: No problem :) Use >!

Comment: Good answer!  However, I would recommend not repeating yourself for multiple lines.  Some of these answers can be explained in further detail (e.g. "crack me open..." would be coconut water, and "directly eat me" would be shredded coconut)

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I need more practice with these riddles!